# The proper kitchen hood

Tags: kitchens, hood

I have the following kitchen setup. The red line is the duct of width of cca 6 inches (15 cm).

[image]

The kitchen is part of a living room which has volume of 90 m3 but is also connected to a hall of cca 26 m3. Right near the stove is a window.

Does it makes in this case to have ducted kitchen hood or in the given setup ductless one might have similar effect?

Will concealing the hood in the top cabinet have effect on its noise and effectiveness?

What are other things to consider in this case?

Comment: Is your range gas or electric?

Comment: Electric. It will be induction range.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Is the end point of your red line a chimney, and is it used for anything else? You can't run the vent right through that wall? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.